# What is the purpose of organization name when we create a new flutter project?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

**What is the purpose of organization name when we create a new flutter project?**

([Check the screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkTwc.png))

Comment: Enter an ID that can uniquely identify the developer

Answer (score 3):

This is called as Application ID in Android and Bundle ID in iOS. It is like a number place in a car, Play store and App Store indentifies application based on these ids. This is useful for OS to identify the application (To check app is installed or not etc). Also it is useful for security purposes like for Facebook Authantication and Firbase setup (To identify request is coming from right client). Please do not use example in your bundle id as with `example` play store will not allow your app to be released.
One more thing. Ideally bundle id should be in reverse company website domain.
Ex : If company website is [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) you should have your bundle id as com.mywebsite.app (.app is optional but it's a good practice to add app).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is the unique id which playstore identifies the developer.
You can add you id as :  for eg. com.company.app

Answer (score 0):

user can identify your Application as uniquely in the play store and no other apps have same organization name